# Prove for Symmetry

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $f:\mathcal{P}(A)$ be the function defined by saying that $f(X)$ is the sum of the elements of X, for each $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. (If $X = \emptyset$, then by convention we say that $f(X) = 0$). Define relations $S,T$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ as follows:

$XSY$ if and only if $f(X)>f(Y)$ or $X = Y$

Write down whether S is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive.

I've asked this question before but it was on reflexivity, and I thought I proved symmetry correctly but upon closer inspection, I am now not so sure.

---

***My Method:***

Symmetric: if $xRy$ then $yRx$, thus it will create 4 cases.

1. if $f(X) > f(Y)$ then $f(Y) > f(X)$ (False)
2. if $X = Y$ then $Y = X$ (True)
3. if $f(X) >f(Y)$ then $Y = X$ (False)
4. if $X = Y$ then $f(Y) > f(X)$ (False)

So is this symmetric? Or is this method wrong?

Comment: No; consider $X= \emptyset$ and $Y = \{ 1 \}$. We have $f(X)=0$ and $f(Y)=1$ and thus (by def $XSY$. But neither $f(Y) < f(X)$ nor $X=Y$, and thus $YSX$ does not hold.

Comment: To prove that the relation is not symmetric you just need to give one example

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you probably meant that $YSX$ but not $XSY$ as $f(X) < f(Y)$ and thus $YSX$ is true

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Thanks for the clarification. Can I ask one more question? Is the relation a transitive relation? Because the way I did it is. Suppose that $f(X)>f(Y)$ AND $Y=Z$ then, $f(X)>Z$ OR $f(X)=Z$. Thus, it is not transitive because $f(X)$ will return an integer and $Z$ is a set, so $f(X)$ cannot be greater than $Z$. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not symmetric.

If $XSY$ for distinct $X,Y$ such that $f(X)>f(Y)$, then neither $f(Y)>f(X)$ nor $Y=X$; then we do not have $YSX.$

Examples abound. See @MauroALLEGRANZA's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249972/prove-for-symmetry#comment8835531_4249972).

---

It is reflexive; indeed, since $X=X$ for all $X$, we have $XSX$ for all $X$.

---

See the comment below for antisymmetry.

---

It is transitive.

Suppose $XSY$ and $YSZ$. If $f(X)>f(Y)$ and $f(Y)>f(Z)$, then $f(X)>f(Z)$ by transitivity of $>$ over the integers. Hence $XSZ$ in this case. The result is clear whenever there is an equality of sets between either $X$ & $Y$ or $Y$ & $Z$ (or both) by simple substitutions.

Comment: Alright, I understand. But I have one more question: Is the relation Antisymmetric in this case? Because all the examples I can think of for this question is that $XSY$ exists but $YSX$ does not exist.

Comment: @BryanHii Suppose $ASB$ and $BSA$. We cannot have $f(A)>f(B)$ nor *vice versa*, since one excludes the other alongside $A=B$; we must then have $A=B$ on its own. Hence $S$ is indeed antisymmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can I ask one more question? Is the relation a transitive relation? Because the way I did it is. Suppose that $f(X) > f(Y)$ AND $Y=Z$ then, $f(X)>Z$ OR $f(X) = Z$. Thus, it is not transitive because $f(X)$ will return an integer and Z is a set, so $f(X)$ cannot be greater than $Z$. Is this wrong?

Comment: I have edited my answer, @BryanHii.

Comment: Also, you're welcome.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation